# Using Javascript to add class to YouTube iframe element

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube, soundcloud

I'm working on a site with a fairly large number of articles. Quite a few have one or more YouTube videos embedded in them via the YT embed code.

Because the design has changed, the height and width of previously embedded videos is no longer in line with the new design. I therefore target the iframe with CSS to show up in the correct dimensions. This works fine, but there are also other iframe objects (Soundcloud player for instance) that inadvertently get resized. Since the YT or SC embed codes don't have classes, I can't target one kind of embed code, and leave the other untouched.

Is it possible to use js to add a class to only YouTube iframe elements, but leave other iframe elements as they are?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this easily by using an attribute selector:

```
$("iframe[src^='http://www.youtube.com']​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​").addClass("myClass");
```

Here's [a working fiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/CTuLN/).

**Additional Info**

Take a look at [jQuery's attribute selector reference](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/). Here's a quick rundown:

```
=  is exactly equal
!= is not equal
^= starts with
$= ends with
*= contains
```

Comment: It's amazing how simple jQuery makes things (and how stupid it makes me look). Thanks so much for pointing this out!

Comment: You don't actually need to use jQuery at all though, attribute selectors are not limited to jQuery but work in all modern (and even not so modern) browsers.

Comment: @powerbuoy, you're correct. In fact, the jQuery docs I linked to reference the fact that they are using css selectors - `The CSS specification also allows elements to be identified by their attributes. While not widely supported by browsers for the purpose of styling documents, these attribute selectors are highly useful, and jQuery allows us to employ them regardless of the browser being used.`. Since jQuery JS & jQuery were tagged, and CSS wasn't, I chose to provide a jQuery example.

Comment: I imagined that either javascript or jquery would be required for this, but definitely good to know CSS selectors could also be used. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, it should be noted though that using pure CSS (which will work in anything from IE7 and up) will be several times faster than using JS.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use an attribute selector, like this:

```
iframe[src^="http://www.youtube"]
```